# Jekyll-Bootstrap gem serving blank page

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up a jekyll project using the jekyll-bootstrap gem, and I have Jekyll 3.2 installed. When I go to the http port it's serving on, I just get a blank page instead of the usual Jekyll index page. Has anyone had this issue? My directory looks like this:

**EDIT:**
It turns out it was actually serving the default.html file in "layouts". But WHY??

[image]

Comment: Difficult to debug with no code. Do you have a repository somewhere ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not authorized to share the code :-/ it turns out, also, that it was unable to find the bootstrap file in 'assets', although it was going down the correct path, it seems....maybe an error in the way bootstrap was getting imported. I think I've got it working now.

Comment: Maybe you can try to reproduce on a fresh install an commit to a demo repository.